# "Expected '}' at end of input". Why do I keep getting this error?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm not a complete newbie so I understand what it means, etc. but I cannot seem to figure out what mysterious bracket Eclipse seems to think I'm missing.

(Ignore the fact that I haven't built what I said I would build in my code--I haven't gotten that far yet.)

```
#include "./BinaryTree.h"
using namespace ods;
typedef BTNode1 Node;
Node * buildNode(Node *p = NULL, Node *l = NULL, Node *r = NULL) {
    Node * ans = new Node;
    ans->parent = p; ans->left = l; ans->right = r;
    return ans;
}

typedef BTNode1 Node;
Node * buildNodeComplete(Node *p = NULL, Node*l = NULL, Node *r = NULL) {
    Node * ans = new Node;
    ans->parent = p; ans->left = l; ans->right = r;
    return ans;
}

typedef BTNode1 Node;
Node * buildNodeStringy(Node *p = NULL, Node*l = NULL, Node *r = NULL) {
    Node * ans = new Node;
    ans->parent = p; ans->left = l; ans->right = r;
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    // build random tree of 1023 nodes
    BinaryTree<Node> T;
    Node *u;
    T.root() = buildNode();
    int d;

    for (int i = 1; i < 1023; ++i) {
        T.randomWalk(u, d);
        if (d == 0) u->left = buildNode(u);
        else u->right = buildNode(u);
    }

    //build complete tree of 1023 nodes
    BinaryTree<BTNode1> C;
    Node *a;
    C.root() = buildNodeComplete();
    int g;

    for (int i = 1; i <1023; i++) {
        C.randomWalk(a, g);
        if (g == 0) a->left = buildNodeComplete(a);
        else a->right = buildNodeComplete(a);
    }

    //build stringy tree of 1023 nodes
    BinaryTree<Node> S;
    Node *q;
    S.root() = buildNodeStringy();
    int v;

    for (int i = 1; i <1023; i++) {
         S.randomWalk(q, v);
         if (v == 0) q->left = buildNodeStringy(q);
         else q->right = buildNodeStringy(q);
    }

    // measure random walks in T
    double sum=0;
    double sum1=0;
    double sum2=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        T.randomWalk(u, d);
        sum += T.depth(u);
        C.randomWalk(a, g);
        sum1 += C.depth(a);
        S.randomWalk(q, v);
        sum2 += S.depth(q);
    }

    std::cout << "Average length of random walk through arbitrary tree is "
              << sum/1000;
    std::cout << " and lg(n+1) = lg(1024) = 10."
              << std::endl;

   //lab 5 part b
    std::cout << "Average length of random walk through complete tree is "
              << sum1/1000 << endl;
    std::cout << "Average length of random walk through stringy tree is "
              << sum2/1000;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check the header file (too)

Comment: if you build you will see where the error is

Comment: The `./` in your include statement is redundant; using `""` in the `#include` statement searches the source file's directory first by default.

Comment: `buildNode`, `buildNodeComplete` and `buildNodeStringy` are the exact same function. Why the repetition? Also why typedef Node three times?

Comment: @harald I'm building different types of trees in `buildNodeComplete` and `buildNodeStringy` but hadn't gotten to it yet. Also, I typed typedef 3 times because I got errors when I didn't so I decided not to question it and left them in there like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly [this bug in Eclipse fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367415), but try adding a new line after the closed parentheses. It used to be required to have a new line character at the end of .cpp files but now it isn't actually necessary.

Also, this looks like a data structures class assignment if I've ever seen one, so good luck on that (it gets harder before it gets easier.)